# Link doesn't work/stops working after font-family inline-styling is added

Tags: html, css, email

I'm editing an EDM created by someone else and working with tables, and for some reason whenever I add in a custom font-family inline style, the font displays correctly, but the hyperlink stops working.

I've tried testing the following (among other things, such as 'Gotham' with the open inverted commas and without (both don't work), with sans-serif and without (both don't work)) to rule other factors out, and narrowed it down to the custom font.

Note: I'm on iOS, using Firefox. I tried viewing on Safari and faced the same issue (the bottom 2 hyperlinks can't be clicked).

Uploaded an example to http://sour-elbow.surge.sh/

1. Using Calibri in the TD styling - works
2. Using Calibri in the a styling - works
3. Using the custom font in the TD styling - doesn't work
4. Using the custom font in the a styling - doesn't work

I also tried using another custom font from Google instead of using a local file (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat), trying both  and @import and both worked fine (font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif) so I'm wondering if the way the custom font Gotham was imported is incorrect? In which case it's a bit strange that it still shows up fine but just causes problems with links.

```
<style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Gotham';
            src: url('fonts/Gotham-Book.eot');
            src: url('fonts/Gotham-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                url('fonts/Gotham-Book.woff2') format('woff2'),
                url('fonts/Gotham-Book.woff') format('woff'),
                url('fonts/Gotham-Book.ttf') format('truetype');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            font-display: swap;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Gotham';
            src: url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.eot');
            src: url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
                url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
                url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
            font-weight: 500;
            font-style: normal;
            font-display: swap;
        }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">
      <a href="test">Test</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="test" style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">Test</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family: Gotham, sans-serif;">
      <a href="test">Test</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="test" style="font-family: Gotham, sans-serif;">Test</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand the syntax you are using in the style attribute value in 3 and 4. Is there some preprocessor involved (in which case please tag it) - what you have shown isn't pure CSS.

Comment: @AHaworth thanks for replying! Sorry it was a typo

Comment: Yes, I think the color's value is missing, should be removed if there is no value assigned to it.

Comment: I think the problem could be that the `href` attribute should accept a link or slug. If you want test it, you could assign it to `"/"` or another page `"/test"`. The missing slash looks odd, and could play a role in not redirecting.

Comment: Please could you make your code into a runnable snippet and test that it really does show the problem. I am unable to reproduce the problem using the code you have given. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Benji, the href value is fine - try it out. Depending on what system you are using it will show you where it 'points to'.

Comment: @Benji colour's been removed, it was a typo here - as for the link, the other tests remain clickable despite not having valid links

Comment: did you included your custom font? are you using a cdn or you have the font locally on your project folder? i think the problem is the way you included the font

Comment: @mmh4all yes I updated my post to show how the font was imported! I tested with another google font and the links also had no issue

Comment: @AHaworth looking into it!

Comment: Thank you for putting up a snppet - but it is not showing any difference in behavior between the two fonts for me. If I run it here then it goes nowhere, if I copy the code and run it locally on my PC it goes to the local file as expected. Have you run the snippet yourself? If so could you describe exactly what the different behaviors are that you are seeing? For example, where does hovering over that link show you what it is pointing to?

Comment: I'm trying to upload a minimal reproducible example - the problem is not showing up without the linked fonts but I'm not sure where to upload them so I can link everything and replicate the issue. Is there a website I can host the fonts on? Or am I allowed to include a wetransfer link with the example and local font files included? Is this against any rules?

Comment: @AHaworth I don't know if this is allowed, but I tried on Surge and you can see the link stop working there in the last 2 examples http://sour-elbow.surge.sh/ I tried using the surge font link directly to create a minimal reproducible example and the font didn't render so I didn't include that in my post above..

Comment: All 4 links behave exactly the same for me on the sour-elbow-surge site you give. I also tried replacing the href value with a real, full url (https://....) and the link worked for me. I am on Edge/Windows 10 at the moment, what are you using?

Comment: @AHaworth I'm using Firefox on iOS (mac), do the last 2 links display the Gotham font for you? Or do they all look the exact same? I just tried on Safari and the last 2 links also don't work..

Comment: No, they don't all look the same. And I've just tried on FF and all works fine. Sorry not to be able to help.